past perfect or past indefinte or both
In my english class we discussed 2 sentences from from a coursebook.

I _ (to know) Sam for about two years whe he _ (to get) married.

and

I _ (already, to know) Sam and Rachel when they _ (to get) married.

Our teacher insists that using the past perfect tense in the first sentence (I had known... when he got married) is completely incorrect, and that only the past simple should be used there. She said the past perfect would only be correct in the second sentence. I'm struggling to understand why the past perfect would be wrong in the first sentence.
Is it actually incorrect, and if so, why?"

Please fix the typo – indefinite – in the question title. And I would use Past Simple instead, but maybe it's another term meaning the same thing.

Here is another post which discusses why "Past Perfect" should be used with "already".
On the other hand, if you leave away the past perfect but keep “already” (“By the time she arrived, the meeting already started”), then you have a conflict in the sentence: the grammar says that she arrived and then the meeting started, but the words say the opposite. That sentence is in conflict in the same way as the sentence: “Yesterday, I will go to school
simple past or past perfect

Your English teacher is wrong in both cases.

I had known Sam for two years when he got married.

(The past perfect is appropriate because the two years since you met Sam happened before the wedding.)

I already knew Sam and Rachel when they got married.

The past perfect is not needed here because it refers to a situation at the time of the wedding, not something that happened before it.

I think in general many learners overuse Past Perfect, but in a case like this I'd infinitely prefer I had already known Sam and Rachel for two years when/before they got married. On the other hand, I'm perfectly happy with your I already knew Sam and Rachel when they got married. I can't explain why including the adverbial clause for two years affects my preference so strongly.

As per the teacher, the correct answers are:


I knew Sam for about two years when he got married.
I had already known Sam and Rachel when they got married.


The teacher advised using the Past Indefinite Tense in the first Sentence for simplicity and clarity.
The Past Perfect Tense, though not incorrect, is considered redundant because of the phrase "for about two years".

Reference ELT Concourse:.
It's fine to have.
He lived for 20 years in France and retired to England.
using two simple past forms because the events are stated in a logical, chronological order.
In this case, the use of the past perfect would be redundant and unnatural.
But if we reverse the order, the past perfect is usually necessary:
He returned to England.  He had lived in France for 20 years or.
He returned to England after he had lived in France..
The Past Perfect

In the second sentence, she suggested using Past Perfect because  "already" is often used with the present perfect and the past perfect.

Reference Cambridge dictionary.
Already: meaning.
We use already to emphasise that something was completed before something else happened.
It is often used with the present perfect or past perfect:
.
The plane had already landed when the pilot announced that there would be a delay in getting to the gate..
already


Reference britishcouncil.org.
Adverbs.
We often use the adverbs already (= 'before the specified time'), still (= as previously), just (= 'a very short time before the specified time'), ever (= 'at any time before the specified time') or never (= 'at no time before the specified time') with the past perfect.
I called his office but he'd already left..
Past Perfect


Per my comment under @Kate's answer, my preference (re when / whether to use the Perfect) seems to be the exact opposite of yours! Very strange.

@FumbleFingers It isn't incorrect. But in the schools they teach to use the Perfect tenses with already. I checked before answering and found it in the Cambridge dictionary.

I studied Eng Lit to degree level, but I'm sure no-one ever explicitly told me anything about using Perfect tenses with already. What I know about things like that comes entirely from a lifetime of speaking, hearing, reading, and writing my own language. And a lifelong interest in language - so, for example, I've read every book written by Steven Pinker. (Indeed, I'm re-reading his excellent Words and Rules right now! :)

@FumbleFingers  Strangely I didn't find anything to the contrary, but British Council website also support. I am following up this to check if anything incorrect is being taught to the students.

The downvoters don't follow Cambridge dictionary/ British Council but go after their home made rules.
